# How do I access the Menu for a Fiat 500e?

Tags: fiat, instrument-cluster

The menu for a 2015 Fiat 500e allows the driver to set the clock, establish a charging schedule, and alter other settings. In determining how to accomplish these tasks, the owner's manual references the Electronic Vehicle Information Center (EVIC) Setup Menu for all of these.

On page 166, the manual instructs the driver

> The setup menu can be activated by pressing the MENU ESC button.
>   Single presses on the + or - buttons will scroll through the setup
>   menu options. The menu includes to following functions:
>
> - Charging Schedule
> - Set Date
> - Set Time

However, whenever I press the `MENU` button, nothing happens when I am driving, and allows me to override the charging schedule if I am not driving, but nothing else. Am I pressing the wrong button or do I have a defective EVIC or how do I access the vehicle's menu?

Comment: If I was the designer, I would not allow you to enter the setup menu when driving... When stationary yes...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was viewing a different screen set. I had to [press the `TRIP` button at the end of the wiper stalk stick](http://www.fiat500usaforum.com/showthread.php?s=6a5fd0375575d2df8fda66d8dd45b487&p=706466#post706466) to cycle through the different views and return to the main view from which I could then access the EVIC Setup Menu.

Page 168 of the manual describes the `TRIP` button and includes a photo:

> ### Trip Button
>
> The TRIP button, located on the right steering column stalk.

Comment: It took me about a week of owning the car before I discovered this; since I purchased it used, I didn't know I wasn't viewing the default screen.